# Using NUXT.js just for static html generation

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

Can you anyone help me?

Does nuxt have any option to exclude `_nuxt` scripts in generate mode?

I need to generate only static html version of Vue app.
Without `_nuxt` folder and included links and script.
I dont need to use javascript on client and those scripts in `_nuxt` former makes my project to heavy.

Basically, I want to use NUXT just for static html generation, NOT Pre-rendering with spa on client.

```
<link href="/_nuxt/manifest.10d0ff23a2bf4f09b86d.js" rel="preload" as="script">
<link href="/_nuxt/vendor.2c4933a76531d246be17.js" rel="preload" as="script">
<link href="/_nuxt/app.b868b05b142119955871.js" rel="preload" as="script">
<link href="/_nuxt/layouts/default.860485f7694926d31a51.js" rel="preload" as="script">
<link href="/_nuxt/pages/index.f4640f8dc2b172dfb993.js" rel="preload" as="script"><link>

<script type="text/javascript">window.__NUXT__={layout:"default",data:[{}],error:null,serverRendered:!0}</script>
<script defer="" src="/_nuxt/manifest.10d0ff23a2bf4f09b86d.js"></script>
<script defer="" src="/_nuxt/layouts/default.860485f7694926d31a51.js"></script>
<script defer="" src="/_nuxt/pages/index.f4640f8dc2b172dfb993.js"></script>
<script defer="" src="/_nuxt/vendor.2c4933a76531d246be17.js"></script>
<script defer="" src="/_nuxt/app.b868b05b142119955871.js"></script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Not yet (and probably never...), because Nuxt.js is fully based on Vue.js SSR, so it needs JS files to work. The `generate` mode it's more a bonus to create website without SSR. But all the engine is based on SSR inse.

For your needs, look for another framework dedicated to create static website: hexo, gatsby, phenomic, hugo, jekyll, ...

Comment: Thanks you. But I already have application written on Vue.js. So the solution what I see it is fork and do it by myself.

Comment: Maybe you can create a Nuxt module that will clean your files on post-build process (just an idea, to check if feasible ^^)